# How to access secured url from ios

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to access a secure url from ios. Basically url will prompt the user with Username and Password. How can I send username and Password from ios?

**My Code**
Here is the Methods that I'm using to access JSON Parser

```
- (NSString *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url{
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                        timeoutInterval:30];
// Fetch the JSON response
NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;

// Make synchronous request
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                returningResponse:&response
                                            error:&error];

// Construct a String around the Data from the response
return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];}


- (id) objectWithUrl:(NSURL *)url{
SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc]init] autorelease];
NSString *jsonString = [self stringWithUrl:url];

// Parse the JSON into an Object
return [jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil]; }
```

Here is the piece of code that I'm retrieving json keys to my dictionary.

```
- (NSDictionary *) downloadFeed {
id response = [self objectWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/Services/Secure.svc/GetList?id=2127"]];

NSDictionary *feed = (NSDictionary *)response;
return feed; }
```

Can someone let me know where can I pass the Username and Password to this url?

Comment: Prompt in what sense? A login form on the website, or [basic HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)?

Comment: Basic HTTP Authentication, I updated my code to get more clear picture!

Comment: Put it here: `http://user:passwd@mysite.com/...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either switch to `ASIHTTPRequest`, which handles Basic authentication simply, or use a `NSMutableRequest` and set the Authorization header correctly, with a base64 encoded user:password pair.

Comment: I'm using ASIHTTPRequest for my login controller. But I'm using JSON Parser after login. Do you think using credential on the url is not secure enough? Well I will use HTTPS on the distribution!

Comment: Where do I assign Username and Password here? 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://@http://mysite.com/Services/Secure.svc/GetList?id=2127"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];

Comment: Security is a separate discussion :-).  request.username = @"user"; request.password = @"password"; - and there is one more flag to set, to force the request to set the basic authentication in the Authorization header.

Comment: And here's that flag: request.authenticationScheme = (NSString *)kCFHTTPAuthenticationSchemeBasic;